# Can I use "the best thing for you" and "the best for you" interchangeably?

Tags: word-usage

I want the best **thing** for you.=I want the best for you.

If I omit "thing", is it ok?

Comment: I think you get better answers if you elaborate a bit more, but, maybe "All the best"

Comment: @Tuomo done....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both sentences are correct and natural.

The first one suggests that there's a bunch of options and I want the best one of those options for you.

The second sounds like I want the best for you in general.

Both are correct in both contexts though.